# Does Cruisecontrol need special account rights?

Tags: security, cruisecontrol

In my cruisecontrol build procedure (msbuild) I'm writing to a logfile. This is the error message that gets displayed

```
 MSBUILD : Logger error MSB4104: Failed to write 
to log file "C:\CruiseControl\projects\Framework\Output\Build". 
Access to the path 'C:\CruiseControl\projects\Framework\Output\Build' is denied.
```

Do anyone know what rights do I need to assign where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the user account that is used to run msbuild does not have access to the output folder 'C:\CruiseControl\projects\Framework\Output\Build'.

Check whether this is really the case and give the appropriate permissions to that user account.

Comment: My assumption as well, I've double checked that my current user has got administrative rights on the folder.  Problem still persists

Comment: @BK: And the current user is also used to run the msbuild process?

Comment: Just to add something here, it is cruisecontrol that kicks off the msbuild process, do I need to set any specific permission there?